# Why is mask not working in my Overlay Plugin in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery-qtip-1.0.0-rc3094652/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery.tablesorter/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery-qtip-1.0.0-rc3094652/jquery.qtip-1.0.0-rc3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.tools.min(4).js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
 $(function() {

    // if the function argument is given to overlay,
    // it is assumed to be the onBeforeLoad event listener
    $(".tool-table a[rel]").overlay({

        mask: 'darkred',
        effect: 'apple',

        onBeforeLoad: function() {

            // grab wrapper element inside content
            var wrap = this.getOverlay().find(".contentWrap");

            // load the page specified in the trigger
            wrap.load(this.getTrigger().attr("href"));
        }

    });
}); 

});

</script>

<style>

/* use a semi-transparent image for the overlay */
    #overlay {
        background-image:url(http://static.flowplayer.org/img/overlay/transparent.png);
        color:#efefef;
        height:450px;
    }

    /* container for external content. uses vertical scrollbar, if needed */
    div.contentWrap {
        height:441px;
        overflow-y:auto;
    }

</style>

<div id="table-of-data-div"> 
        <div id="table-div">
                <table id="box-table-a" class="tablesorter">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                        <th scope="col" style="cursor:pointer;">B-House/Dorm Name</th>
                                        <th scope="col" style="cursor:pointer;">Address</th>
                                        <th scope="col" style="cursor:pointer;">Price Range</th>
                                        <th scope="col" style="cursor:pointer;">Date Added</th>
                                        <th scope="col" style="cursor:pointer;">Status</th>

                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                   <?php



                                   $q=mysql_query("select * from property");
                                        while( $f=mysql_fetch_array($q, MYSQL_ASSOC))
                                        {
                                        $p_id=$f["p_id"];

                                   echo"

                                        <tr>
                                            <td class='tool-table'>
                                            <span class='tool-id' style='display:none'>".$p_id."</span>
                                            <span id='testid' style='cursor:pointer'><a id='wala' href='profile-test.php?q=$p_id' rel='#overlay' style='text-decoration:none; color:#339;'>".$f['p_name']."</a></span></td>
                                            <td id='pretty'>".$f['address']."</td>
                                            <td>".$f['p_name']."</td>
                                            <td>".$f['payment_type']."</td>      
                                            <td>".$status."</td>       
                                        </tr>       


                                    ";

                                    }



                                    ?>
                                        </tbody>

                </table>
                <div class="apple_overlay" id="overlay">

                <!-- the external content of overlay is loaded inside this tag -->
                <div class="contentWrap"></div>

                </div>


        </div>

    </div>
```

i have screenshot

[image: http://imgur.com/zWxoX]

Comment: It's not a very good idea to host screenshots on a site that requires login before showing them. Try imgur.com or similar next time.

Comment: i uploaded it now to imgur.com. please help

Comment: Can you narrow this down to a specific question, and remove extraneous code?

Comment: this is the only necessary code ive cropped from my code. my question is that why doesnt the plugin working properly.. im using overlay plugin from flowplayer

Comment: OK. just this question. WHY IS THE MASK NOT WORKING?

Comment: -1 for shouting. "PLEASE HEEEEEEELP" in title and SHOUTING won't help you get any more help than you'll get without this.

Comment: cmon. im desperate here.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Be sure that your jquery tools javascript includes expose.  This library is used to display the mask.

Comment: Thank you! You have just saved me an hour of bewilderment. :)

Comment: Anyway for someone other than the poster to 'mark as answer' on SO?

Comment: Thank you thank you. I spent 2 hours working on this and it was that simple.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm I am not too sure where you want your overlay, but if you want the overlay placed directly over the whole site, then try moving out your overlay wrapper, assuming it is the '#overlay', so it is as a direct child of 'body' or as a sibling of '#table-of-data-div'.

Comment: yes. i want the overlay to be whole. so that the user cant interact in the background while the overlay is open. but when i load the page.. the #overlay div is already there, which is not suppose to be there.

Comment: how to make the #overlay div to be direct child of my table? can you explain that child or sibling concept?please. and also the mask is not shown too. mask is the one that prevents the user not to interact with the background of the overlay. can you help me with that too?

Comment: I am assuming the above code is a snippet of the whole page because I don't see a "<body>" or "<head>" tag. Try placing the "<div class="apple_overlay" id="overlay">" right before "</body>" so that will allow the component to "overlay". Other things you will need to reconsider is your CSS to create this effect. I don't know how it was implemented. It might be best to start as a starting point with one of jQuery tools demos: [http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/overlay/index.html](http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/overlay/index.html).

Comment: yes it is. ive tried placing the div overlay just before the </body> but it will still display in the page before i click the trigger of the overlay.. it's suppose to display only when i trigger teh overlay.

Comment: If that's the case, then the issue may be tied to the CSS. Did you define a CSS style "display:none" on your overlay?

Comment: yes ive tried that.. but its not suppose to be with that style cause the overlay plugin handles it all. ive copied everything from the plugin..

Comment: OK. just this question. WHY IS THE MASK NOT WORKING?

Comment: Well I am assuming you are using jquery tools. If you look into the setup of the jquery tools overlay, it does initialize the overlay to be hidden (display:none).  The mask is controlled by CSS. Again, you can use this demo for reference and work your way. Here's the link again [http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/overlay/index.html](http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/overlay/index.html). It's best to strip your functionality to the bare minimum where you get the overlay working. And when that is working, start plugging back other features.